# Vlookup Multiple Criteria C#

Tags: c#, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two datagridviews:
datagridView1, with col A and B (Cells[0], Cells[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh5ej.png)):

[image]

`datagridView2 (Cells[0], Cells[1], Cells[2]):`

[image]

I would like to compare the value in between two tables and if:
- `the value in datagridView1.rows[i].Cells[0].value = datagridView2.rows[j].Cells[0].value AND the value in datagridView1.rows[i].Cells[1].value = datagridView2.rows[j].Cells[1].value THEN write in datagridView1.rows[i].Cells[2].value the value from the third column in datagridView2:`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this. It would depend on how you are populating your `DataGridView`s. There is also no error handling which should be implemented.

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var r1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    var r2 = dataGridView2.Rows[i];

    if (r1.Cells[0].Value == r2.Cells[0] && r1.Cells[1].Value == r2.Cells[1])
        r1.Cells[2].Value = r2.Cells[2].Value;
}
```

Comment: I'm populating data from an excel file. Should convert datagridView cell's to string first.

Comment: I have amended your code by adding another 'for loop', so the variable i is counting rows in datagridView1 and the variable j is counting rows in datagridView2. It works well, but only if I have empty cells. If I populate with data cannot match it anymore.

Comment: this seem to be working only if the matched cells are on the same row.

Comment: I thought that is what you wanted by the description of your question. If you want to match any row you need two for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the second loop I've added to match any row and works fine:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < src1.Rows.Count; i++)

        {
            var r1 = src1.Rows[i];

            for (var j = 1; j < src2.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                var r2 = src2.Rows[j];

                if (r1[0].Equals(r2[0]) && r1[1].Equals(r2[1]))
                {
                    r1[2] = r2[2];
                }
            }
        }
```